# How to get the convex hull of a binary image using DIPlib in C++?

Tags: c++, image-processing, diplib

I have a stack of binary images of an open porous structure and I want to get a binary mask which covers the whole volume of the structure (the structure itself and the void contained in the structure). I think a good way to achieve my goal would be to calculate the convex hull of the image. This works fine in Python using `skimage.morphology.convex_hull_image` (see images).

[image: input]

[image: result]

But I need this functionality in C++ and I want to use the DIPlib library. Unfortunately I'm struggeling with the correct implementation since the documentation confuses me a bit.

1. Could you provide a minimal example which explains how to derive the the convex hull of a binary object as an image?
2. Does the DIPlib implementation also handle 3D images?

Comment: Why not use a C++ library that deals with Delaunay Triangles and insert the white pixels as points?  It will give you the convex hull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use the function [`dip::MakeRegionsConvex2D()`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/regions.html#dip-MakeRegionsConvex2D-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-String-CL). For example:

```cpp
dip::Image img = dip.ImageRead('yIFuP.jpg');
dip::Image bin = img > 128;  // assuming img is scalar
dip::MakeRegionsConvex2D(bin, bin);
```

This function is explicitly written for 2D images, and will not work for 3D images.

For a 3D image, I would get a list of the coordinates of all set pixels (use [`dip::Find`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/analysis.html#dip-Find-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL)), and pass that into a quickhull algorithm implementation such as [the one in CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/index.html), then draw the resulting 3D polyhedron into the image. This last step might be the most challenging one (I don't know if CGAL has functionality to render a polyhedron to an image). The quick and dirty solution would be to iterate over all pixels, and for each do a in/out test, set the pixel if it's inside the polyhedron.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helps a lot. I would like to mention that this feature seems to have been implemented only recently in the latest version of DIPlib, namely version 3.3. I still was on version 3.1 or so and wondered why it didn't work at first. But upgrading to the latest version solved the issue.